# Modifying contents of vector in BOOST_FOREACH

Tags: c++, boost, vector, foreach

This is a question that goes to how BOOST_FOREACH checks it's loop termination

```
cout << "Testing BOOST_FOREACH" << endl;
vector<int> numbers; numbers.reserve(8);
numbers.push_back(1); numbers.push_back(2); numbers.push_back(3);
cout << "capacity = " << numbers.capacity() << endl;
BOOST_FOREACH(int elem, numbers)
{
    cout << elem << endl;
    if (elem == 2) numbers.push_back(4); 
}
cout << "capacity = " << numbers.capacity() << endl;
```

gives the output

```
Testing BOOST_FOREACH
capacity = 8
1
2
3
capacity = 8
```

But what about the number 4 which was inserted half way through the loop? If I change the type to a list the newly inserted number will be iterated over. The vector push_back operation will invalidate any pointers IF a reallocation is required, however that is not happening in this example. So the question I guess is why does the end() iterator appear to only be evaluated once (before the loop) when using vector but has a more dynamic evaluation when using a list?

Comment: I get an assertion running your code, Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: @Gman:  to get it to work under Visual Studio 2008, you have to disable iterator debugging (`/D_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0`).

Comment: Doesn't that kinda defeat the purpose? You're doing something in undefined behavior land. **Fix warnings, don't silence them.** That's like having a compiler that warns you when you go outside the bounds of the array, but you disable that so you can do it anyway.

Comment: I didn't say it was a _good idea_ in practice (it's not, I agree; it's a terrible idea); I just said that in order to get his example to work, iterator debugging needs to be disabled.

Comment: Oops, I read the "Ja-" and assumed you were the OP. Silly me still not used to looking for the highlighted asker names. Okay, I assume you know about warnings then. :P

Comment: compiled fine under g++ 4.3.3 on ubuntu... Although I can see how this could be unstable code, if the vector is reallocated during the middle of the loop the iterators will be left pointing at freed memory.

Comment: @GMan:  No problem :-).  @Jamie Cook:  I've posted an answer below explaining _why_ the Microsoft debug runtime raises an assertion, which also explains why you should not do this.

Comment: @James McNellis: thats awesome, I've accepted your answer; thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Under the covers, BOOST_FOREACH uses
>   iterators to traverse the element
>   sequence. Before the loop is executed,
>   the end iterator is cached in a local
>   variable. This is called hoisting, and
>   it is an important optimization. It
>   assumes, however, that the end
>   iterator of the sequence is stable. It
>   usually is, but if we modify the
>   sequence by adding or removing
>   elements while we are iterating over
>   it, we may end up hoisting ourselves
>   on our own petard.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/foreach/pitfalls.html

If you don't want the end() iterator to change use resize on the vector rather than reserve.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/

Note that then you wouldn't want to push_back but use the operator[] instead.  But be careful of going out of bounds.

Comment: right, sorry thought he was asking why the size didn't change =)
changing my answer =)

Comment: From that same link: 
The moral of the story is to think twice before adding and removing elements from the sequence over which you are iterating. If doing so could cause iterators to become invalid, don't do it. Use a regular for  loop instead.

Comment: Ahhhh that explains a lot, except for why it works for a list? My guess is that .end() of a list actually returns NULL (or similar constant) because lists are implemented as doubly linked lists... so the last element of the list is defined as the element where .next() returns null which doesn't change when you add/remove elements. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: not sure what std::list uses as end(), but it doesn't matter.  
But the sgi site says this about lists:
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html

"Lists have the important property that insertion and splicing do not invalidate iterators to list elements, and that even removal invalidates only the iterators that point to the elements that are removed."  And end() is a iterator of the list so it should not be invalidated for an insert operation.

Answer (score 2):

The question was raised in the comments as to why the Microsoft debug runtime raises an assertion during iteration over the vector but not over the list.  The reason is that `insert` is defined differently for `list` and `vector` (note that `push_back` is just an `insert` at the end of the sequence).

Per the C++ standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2003 23.2.4.3, *vector modifiers*):

> [on insertion], if no reallocation happens, all the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid.

(23.2.2.3, *list modifiers*):

> [insert] does not affect the validity of iterators and references.

So, if you use `push_back` (and are sure that it's not going to cause a reallocation), it's okay with either container to continue using your iterator to iterate over the rest of the sequence.

In the case of the vector, however, it's **undefined behavior** to use the `end` iterator that you obtained before the `push_back`.

*This is a roundabout answer to the question; it's a direct answer to the discussion in the question's comments.*

Answer (score 0):

boost's foreach will terminate when it's iterator == numbers.end()

Be careful though, calling push_back can/will invalidate any current iterators you have.

Comment: Not any, only those which follow the insertion, unless the vector grows beyond its `capacity()` (and note how he uses `reserve()`).